# Can anyone fix these issues with flutter doctor issues with android toolchain and android studio?

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies

Can anyone help me fix this issue setting up Flutter.

I have a couple of errors, specifically issues across two categories.

**Issue 1**

`[!] Android toolchain` - I'm having a (seemingly common) unknown license status issue. However, common fixes have not worked, such as `flutter doctor --android-licenses`,  which can be seen in the console output below.

**Issue 2**

`[!] Android studio` - The second problem is the location of android studio is not working, I was getting `[!] Android Studio (not installed)`, so then I tried using `flutter config --android-studio-dir=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\`. Now I'm getting the two issues of:

```sh
[!] Android Studio
    X android-studio-dir = C:\Program
    X Android Studio not found at C:\Program
```

This is also visible below.

Here is the reduced console output, only showing the issues:

```sh
C:\Users\anonymous\OneDrive\Documents\Frameworks\flutter>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[!] Android Studio
    X android-studio-dir = C:\Program
    X Android Studio not found at C:\Program

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

C:\Users\anonymous\OneDrive\Documents\Frameworks\flutter>flutter doctor -v

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16.0.1+9-24)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.

[!] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at C:\Program
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    X android-studio-dir = C:\Program
    X Android Studio not found at C:\Program
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.
    • Consider removing your android-studio-dir setting by running:
      flutter config --android-studio-dir=

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

C:\Users\anonymous\OneDrive\Documents\Frameworks\flutter>flutter doctor --android-licenses
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
        ... 5 more
```

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Start by reading and following the instructions given.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice It's kind of like jargon, I'm not sure what instructions I'm meant to be following. I see the exception errors, but I have no clue how to resolve this.

Comment: Learning this "jargon" and how to read error output is an important part of becoming a computer programmer. I suggest scanning down each line to see if there is anything that is clear instructions for how to resolve the problem.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yeah, I have, I cannot resolve issue 1, going to the link it directs you to, does not yield any useful information. Issue 2 has been solved though.

Comment: Read the line before the link

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I ran that, as stated in the question body. It just fails, as you can also see at the bottom of the question body

Comment: What is the output when you run `flutter doctor --android-licenses`? Please [edit] your question to show this.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to issue 2 was that you did the wrong syntax for the command `flutter config --android-studio-dir=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\`

It should have been `flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"`

You were missing the quotation marks around the filepath.